# Why char* directly set the value but not in the case of int* in c programming

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, string-literals

> There is no existence of string as a primitive data type in c
> language. char* make string exist. If a list of character set to an
> pointer like this (char *msg = "HI!") but why not in the case of
> pointer of type int like this (int *p = 10)?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *msg = "HI!";
    int *p = 2;
    
    printf("%p\n", msg);
    printf("%p\n", &msg[0]);
    printf("%p\n", p);
}
```

I got an error message when I tried to compile it. Error message down below:

```
pointers.c:6:10: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'int' [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
    int *p = 2;
         ^   ~
1 error generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: pointers] Error 1
```

Comment: `2` is an `int`, not a pointer. But `"HI!"` is a string literal which is a pointer to that string, IOW it's a `char*`.

Comment: They are not different. The `char *msg = "HI!";` is assigning the value you gave to the pointer (the address of a string literal), just as with `int *p = 2;` (an invalid address).

Comment: "char* make string exist" No, that is not enough, and there is still no string type: a C string is an array of characters *with a NUL value end marker/sentinel*.

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
char *msg = "HI!";
```

several special things are happening.  First, the string literal `"HI!"` is treated like an anonymous array

```
char anonymous_array[] = "HI!";
```

(This treatment of string literals is one and perhaps the only way in which the C language *does* support the notion of a "string type".)

Second, when you attempt to use the value of this array, what you get (as you just about always do in C) is a pointer to the array's first element:

```
char *msg = &anonymous_array[0];
```

And that works well.  On the other hand, when you say

```
int *p = 2;
```

nothing like that happens.  If anything, this tells the compiler *not* that you want a pointer `p` pointing at the integer 2, but rather, that you want a pointer `p` that points at *memory address 2*.  But your program probably doesn't have access to memory address 2, and even if it did, for a normal program, there's no way to know what's at that address, and nothing meaningful you could do with it.  (If you're doing embedded programming, on the other hand, you might know that there's something interesting at that address for your particular architecture.)

If you want `p` to point to an integer object with the value 2, you'll need to create that integer object somehow.  You could do

```
int i = 2;
int *p = &i;
```

or

```
int array[] = { 2 };
int *p = array;
```

Or — and this ends up being much closer to the way string initialization works — you can use a special syntax called a *compound literal*:

```
int *p = (int []){ 2 };
```

Comment: That was a good representation .I understood that matter. But why not you use a & before array in the last line when  you tried to get the pointer of the array using *p?

Comment: Because when you attempt to use an array as an initializer, what you get (as always in C) is a pointer to the array's first element.  So when I write `int *p = array;`, what I get (what the compiler does for me) is exactly as if I wrote `int *p = &array[0];` explicitly.  This is a surprising but basic and important fact in C.  If you haven't gotten to the "arrays and pointers" chapter in your C textbook yet, you might want to go and read it now.

Comment: This answer could add, that string literals are read-only, and change the `anonymous_array` to be const. It's a detail, but somewhat important detail.

Answer (score -1):

String literals have types of character arrays. For example the string literal     `"HI!"` has type `char[4]`. You can check that with this simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( "HI!" ) );
}
```

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 6 In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to
> each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal
> or literals.78) **The multibyte character sequence is then used to
> initialize an array of static storage duration** and length just
> sufficient to contain the sequence.

Used in expressions array designators with rare exceptions are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements like in this declaration

```
char *msg = "HI!";
```

that is equivalent to

```
char *msg = &"HI!"[0];
```

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

So if you had an integer array like

```
int a[] = { 2 };
```

you could write

```
int *p = a;
```